# Open remote session (not screen sharing)

Tags: macos, mac-mini, remote-desktop

I have a mac mini that I'd like to use from my MacBook Air. So far, the only thing I have been able to do is setup the built-in Apple's Screen Sharing, which I have found really unreliable and slow.

I was hoping to find an alternative similar to what Microsoft Remote Desktop provides, i.e. **not a screen sharing** service via VNC, but a remote session login, **agnostic** of the mac mini's display and current session(s) running.

Once again, I'm not looking for setting up screen sharing. My mini does not even have a display.

**Edit**: I also want to be able to use the UI, not just the command line, so `ssh` is not an option in this case.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Screen sharing is too slow?

Comment: That's one of the problems, yes. But the main one is that my air has a small screen, and for some reason the mini has a quite big resolution. So it's difficult to work since everything is scaled. Displays option in System Preferences does not allow me to change the resolution.

Comment: When I connect to a mac using screen sharing, an app called Screen Sharing opens. In that app's preferences you should make sure "Scale to fit available space" and "Adapt Quality to network conditions (faster)" are selected.

Comment: Those options are set already. The main problem is that the whole Share Screen experience provided by OSX, runs on top of VNC. I'm perplexed. Windows guys have had RDP for almost 17 years ago.

Comment: I don't know what it does, or if it uses VNC, but there is Apple Remote Desktop for $80.

Comment: Yup... I also have it. It's basically the same Share Screen app (VNC), with a few premium features (like curtain mode, and others). But, again, it does not do what I'd like to to.

Comment: VNC is a younger technology than RDP and I have success managing multiple computers via Screen Sharing.app and Apple's Remote Desktop.app. Have you tried TeamViewer?

Comment: Yup... to my surprise it sometimes works better than Screen Sharing.app... I'm also taking a look at iRapp. It's paid, but at least it feels like RDP.